# Office 365 - Mailboxes

Tags: powershell, email, outlook, office365

I currently have a list of 600+ newly created mailboxes within Office 365. However the problem I'm facing is, I need to create an automatic reply for the previous 600+ mailboxes to the new mailboxes within a short space of time.

For example:

**123@abc.com will receive an email from the customer, 123@abc.com will then send an automated email back to the customer advising them to contact the new mailbox 123.456@abc.com**

I understand I could in fact forward the email to the new mailbox however, the specification I've received wants to avoid that situation if possible.

How could I use a powershell script to create an autoreply for the 600+ mailboxes that I have within my xls spreadsheet* without having to manually change all mailboxes myself?

*Within the spreadsheet contains two columns, column one contains previous mailbox address and column two containing the newly created mailbox address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variant of the code below should work.

```
# Might need to do some magic with -encoding and -delimiter below
$Import = Import-Csv "\\server\share\mailboxes.csv"

# Loop through all the lines in the csv
foreach ($Line in $Import)
{
# Assuming two columns, one with header "oldmailbox" and one with header "newmailbox"
$OldMailBox = $Line.oldmailbox; $NewMailBox = $Line.newmailbox

# Enable autoreply and set a message
Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -Identity $OldMailBox -AutoReplyState Enabled -ExternalMessage "Send mail to $NewMailBox"
}
```

Additional information can be found here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638217(v=exchg.160).aspx

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you very much this is what I've been looking for